# 64 bit program reading 32bit created registry item Delphi5

Tags: registry

Registry Q's on this subject have not looked at the issue from this aspect.
My Delphi5 program writes a registry item to
**`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE SOFTWARE\grange\MyApp`**
The actual entry in the registry is in :
**`Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\VirtualStore\MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\grange`**
But this is not a problem, because my other Delphi programs using the original address work correctly.
My question is:
Will any other 64 bit program find the entry just using
 **`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE SOFTWARE\grange\MyApp`** ?
These will be other third party applications written in various languages.

Comment: No, not unless they specifically request 32-bit view. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384129%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Thanks Sertac, you are correct. I have managed to get a 64bit application to read the registry and I have to be specific to specify the Wow6432 node to get the value. Do I have to tell any third party user to use the appropriate registry key, or is there a better way?

Comment: You're welcome. I can't think of any other way, they have to know the regular key (HKLM/Software..) and that this is a 32bit application. Then it's their decision to either use the 32bit view or to directly access the wow6432node key - although it's not suggested/supported. But consider tagging your question with 'Delphi' or language/compiler you use, so that it's seen by more experts, maybe someone thinks something else...